# php mock ->expects() does NOT report an error when not called

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have the following mock object:

```
$permutator = $this->getMockBuilder('PermutationClass', 
array('get_permutation'))->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

$permutator->expects($this->at(0))
                  ->method('get_permutation')
                  ->will($this->returnCallback(function($praram1) {
                        return true;
                  }));
$permutator->expects($this->at(1))
                  ->method('get_permutation')
                  ->will($this->returnCallback(function($praram1) {
                        return true;
                  }));
```

However, what I have experienced is that if for some reason the call at "1" never gets executed, then there are no errors reported regarding an expectation never being met.

If I add the following code: right before the expects:

```
$permutator->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('get_permutation');
```

Then what happens is that an error will be reported if a given expectation was never called. HOWEVER, what happens here is that for some reason, this makes the return value of the mock object to be NULL since I didn't set it. If I set it like so:

```
$permutator->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('get_permutation')->will($this->returnValue("THIS SHOULD NEVER BE RETURNED"));
```

Then this becomes the return value for all of the expected method calls for that function. So at(0) and at(1) do get executed( I set some print statements ) but the return value is overriden by this:

```
$permutator->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('get_permutation');
```

I managed to get the expected behavior using:

```
$permutator->expects($this->exactly(2))
           ->method('get_permutation')
           ->will( $this->onConsecutiveCalls(
                       $this->returnCallback(function($praram1) {
                           return true;
                       }),
                       $this->returnCallback(function($praram1) {
                           return false;
                       })
                   )
           );
```

What I am getting at is why would the mock object not complain that say $this->at(1) is never called when I've clearly set an expectation?

Comment: Are you sure that the method is not being called?  I made a simple example using $this->at() and it fails the test if the method is called only once.  I think that there is something else going on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mockery, you can create `spy` instead of `mock`, and then use `shouldNotHaveReceived` at the end of your test, this way you'll get an error if method have been called.
something like this:

```
$dependency = Mockery::spy(YourDependencyClass::class);
$sut = new SystemUnderTest($dependency);
$sut->execute();
$dependency->shouldNotHaveReceived('method');
```

Answer (score -1):

That is not what `expects` does - all it does is tell the mock what to return when that function gets called.  It is *not* an assertion.

If you want to assert that a method was called, I would look into https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy#spies

Alternatively, you could use `returnCallback` to save which params were called, and then compare that to what you know it should be, so something like:

```
$params = [];
$permutator->expects($this->any())
->method('get_permutation')
->will($this->returnCallback(
    function($param) use (&$params){
        $params[] = $param);
    }
));

doTheThing();

$this->assertEquals(
  array(1,2),
  $params
);
```

Comment: I see your point. Although, "->expects($this->exactly(2))->..." does exactly that. However, I guess my expectation of the "->expects(at(...))" was not entirely correct. I managed to achieve what I was trying to do onConsecutiveCalls.

Comment: `expects()` sets up an expectation that is verified at the end of the test. An expectation is an assertion.